# Detect all distinct k-th powers in a string for all k ≥ 3

Tags: algorithms, strings

In string theory, the $k$-th power of a string $w$ is named as $w^k$, where $w^0$ is the empty string $\epsilon$ and $w^n$ is the concatenation of $w$ and $w^{n - 1}$ $(n \in \mathbb{N}^{+})$.

The power in a string that mentioned below means some power which is one substring of the string. In addition, two strings are distinct if they don't look the same.

In [Maxime Crochemore, et al. *Number of Occurrences of powers in Strings*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220180770_Number_of_Occurrences_of_powers_in_Strings), **theorem 3** claims that "*The number of distinct $k$-th powers, for a fixed integer $k \geq 3$, in a string of length $n$ is at most $\frac{n}{k-2}$*".

If it is true, we may conclude the number of all distinct $k$-th powers for all integers $k \geq 3$ in a string of length $n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$.

Is it possible to detect all these powers through some method in time complexity $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$? For example, count the number of them and list one occurrence (start index and end index) for each of them.

I failed to seek results in recent research...

I asked the same question at [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309877/algorithm-detecting-all-distinct-k-th-powers-in-a-string-for-all-k-%E2%89%A5-3).